# Copying multiple text lines into a file after specified pattern using shell

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk, sed

I want to insert multiple line from **file1** marked with pattern into a **file2** using shell.
The pattern is 10 numbers, always different input exmple: "2016854218"

file1 example **(input)**:

```
[...]
    <a class="none" data-container="#fr_5854841" href="https://example.com/profiles/2016854218"></a>
    <div class="new_cl">
        <img src="2016854218_medium.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blocker">Novaa<br>
        <span class="friend_small_text">
[...]
```

file2 example **(output)**:

```
2016854218
2016859711
2017076181
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify exactly the steps that'd lead to getting that output from that input.

Comment: @PesaThe I tried notepad++... not dealing with bash console so much.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm trying to get this on output. Don't know how to do this, Sir.

Comment: We understand you don't know HOW to do it, we're asking you to tell us WHAT it is you're trying to do. Are you trying to print every 10-digit number from the input, or just the number from `href="https://example.com/profiles/2016854218"` or just the number from `src="2016854218_medium.jpg"` or something else? Where did the other 2 numbers in the expected output come from - are they somewhere else in the input (if so include them in the example) or are you generating them by some algorithm or something else? And so on...

Comment: Also working awk -F'href="' '{print $2}' a |rev | cut -c 4- | rev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP wants to have `http` link's complete value till all the digits s adding this solution now too.

```
awk --re-interval 'match($0,/https:.*[0-9]{10}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

---

Could you please first if you have control M characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` if yes then run `dos2unix` utility in case you have it. In case you don't have it use:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

but above will remove all control M characters, so to remove control Ms on last of the line(in case) use:

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Now once your control Ms are not there on Input_file then you could use following:

```
awk --re-interval 'match($0,/[0-9]{10}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file > Output_file
```

You could remove `--re-interval` in case you have newer version of GNU `awk` with you.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -Eo '\d{10}' file1 > file2`

Comment: Thanks for trying but this command not working. file2 (output) is empty.

Comment: please add a simple explanation to your answer.thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk -F'href="' '{print $2}' a |rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

This will cut whole input text to only link.

Input:

```
[...]
    <a class="none" data-container="#fr_5854841" href="https://example.com/profiles/2016854218"></a>
    <div class="new_cl">
        <img src="2016854218_medium.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="blocker">Novaa<br>
        <span class="friend_small_text">
[...]
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/profiles/2016854218
```

Comment: That's a fragile, complicated, inefficient approach and the output doesn't match the output you said you wanted. If you had told us what it is you wanted to do you'd have a good solution by now instead you've go 2 answers posted that don't do what your own solution it trying to do, you've accepted one of them which will discourage anyone else from posting an answer, and you've got your own solution which is the wrong way to do anything and you STILL haven't updated your question to explain exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: @Andrzej Strzelba, please check my EDIT answer and let me know if this helps but you should really be telling all your requirements in a single post itself else it will be difficult for people to understand question.